# Unable to create a Glympse account

Tags: glympse

I've tried on multiple phones now (different people's phone numbers), and every time I try to create an account in the Glympse App (Android), I get an "invalid number" error.

Since the app gets my phone number directly from Android, I thought maybe this had to do with formatting. But I've tried all of the following formats, and got the same error every time:

- 0000000000
- 000-000-0000
- 000.000.0000
- (000) 000-0000

It's not like Glympse has a username/password system, and someone has already registered this phone number or anything like that. It's my real and only phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a system wide recaptcha failure. I have been contacting glympse for around 15 days and no one has replied as of yet.

You cannot setup a developer account because the recaptcha is not working correctly despite it turning green like it should when you get the answers right. I am hoping glympse will respond soon as we are sitting around waiting to start. :)

Comment: Thank you for the perspective. I'm going to hope your hypothesis is correct, and that they'll fix it soon.

Comment: You are welcome. Its only been 15 days, maybe one week, they will  be back online. :) But I am sure they went out of business. I tried the phone, email, I tracked down employees on Facebook and asked them and not one of them replied to me for over a week. One person replied saying contacting support. Maybe we find a new site to use?

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was the same issue and I was trying to fix it for several hours and after all I fount a solution that worked for me. By default, if you have a micro-sd card in the mobile android will install some apps on the sd card. In the case of this software, it is causing this error. So go to ur settings - storage - apps and select glympse and change the storage to internal memory for this app. Relaunce the app and u should register ur mobile number without any problems. Atleast in my case i hope this will help you. Please let me know.

Comment: My phone doesn't have an SD card